# How to restrict the file types in FileUpload in MVC3?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, file-upload

I have a fileupload function where users can upload files. I want to restrict the users from upload certain file types. The types allowed are: **.doc,.xlsx,.txt,.jpeg**.

How I can do this?

This is my actual file upload code:

```
      public ActionResult UploadFile(string AttachmentName, BugModel model)
       {            
        BugModel bug = null;
        if (Session["CaptureData"] == null)
        {
            bug = model;
        }
        else
        {
            bug = (BugModel)Session["CaptureData"];
        }
        foreach (string inputTagName in Request.Files)
        {
            HttpPostedFileBase file1 = Request.Files[inputTagName];
            if (file1.ContentLength > 0)
            {
                string path = "/Content/UploadedFiles/" + Path.GetFileName(file1.FileName);
                string savedFileName = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~" + path));
                file1.SaveAs(savedFileName);
                BugAttachment attachment = new BugAttachment();
                attachment.FileName = "~" + path.ToString();
                attachment.AttachmentName = AttachmentName;
                attachment.AttachmentUrl = attachment.FileName;
                bug.ListFile.Add(attachment);
                model = bug;
                Session["CaptureData"] = model;
            }
        }
        ModelState.Clear();
        return View("LoadBug", bug);
    }
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The first thing to verify is whether the file extension contained in `file1.FileName` matches one of the allowed extensions. Then if you really want to ensure that the user hasn't renamed some other file type to an allowed extension you will need to look into the contents of the file to recognize whether it is one of the allowed types.

Here's an example how to check whether the file extension belongs to a list of predefined extensions:

```
var allowedExtensions = new[] { ".doc", ".xlsx", ".txt", ".jpeg" };
var extension = Path.GetExtension(file1.FileName);
if (!allowedExtensions.Contains(extension))
{
    // Not allowed
}
```

Comment: @Darrin Dimitrov...thanks its done and i am showing this uploaded files in table before saving the in Database...if a user wants to delete one of the uploaded file how can i do this...

Answer (score 8):

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property, AllowMultiple = false)]
public class AllowedFileExtensionAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    public string[] AllowedFileExtensions { get; private set; }
    public AllowedFileExtensionAttribute(params string[] allowedFileExtensions)
    {
        AllowedFileExtensions = allowedFileExtensions;
    }
    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        var file = value as HttpPostedFileBase;
        if (file != null)
        {
            if (!AllowedFileExtensions.Any(item => file.FileName.EndsWith(item, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)))
            {
                return new ValidationResult(string.Format("{1} için izin verilen dosya uzantıları : {0} : {2}", string.Join(", ", AllowedFileExtensions), validationContext.DisplayName, this.ErrorMessage));
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Usage In Model

```
    [AllowedFileExtension(".jpg", ".png", ".gif", ".jpeg")]
    public HttpPostedFileBase KategoriResmi { get; set; }
```

Comment: this is the actual answer

Comment: This is the actual and concise answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 7):

You can use the `ContentType` property of the `HttpPostedFileBase` for a basic check of the file type (mime type): [See MSDN's page on the Content-Type property here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httppostedfilebase.contenttype.aspx)

Here is one way to do it:

```
private static bool IsValidContentType(string contentType)
{
    string ct = contentType.ToLower();

    return ((ct == "application/msword") || (ct == "application/pdf") || (ct == "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document"));
}
```

etc..

However, for a deeper inspection, you will have to inspect the file content. It's easy to change a file extension..